TRPCClientError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
Im using nextjs app router, trpc, prisma, and trying to implement login functionality with setting a cookie. Im trying to set cookie in res headers, but i get this error. I cannot figure out why?
login.tsx:29 Error:  TRPCClientError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at TRPCClientError.from (TRPCClientError.mjs:40:20)
    at eval (httpBatchStreamLink.mjs:125:106)

Here is my code:
my user.ts // user router
import { db } from "@/server/db";
import { createTRPCRouter, publicProcedure } from "../trpc";
import { UserCreateInputSchema } from "prisma/generated/zod";
import { hashPassword, verifyPassword } from "@/util/hashing";
import { z } from "zod";
import { encrypt, login } from "@/lib";

export const userRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  create: publicProcedure
    .input(UserCreateInputSchema)
    .mutation(async ({ input }) => {
      const { email, password, username, first_name, last_name } = input;

      const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);

      await db.user.create({
        data: {
          email,
          password: hashedPassword,
          username,
          first_name,
          last_name,
        },
      });
    }),
  getByUsername: publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({ username: z.string() }))
    .query(async ({ input }) => {
      return db.user.findUnique({ where: { username: input.username } });
    }),
  login: publicProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        username: z.string(),
        password: z.string().min(6),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ input, ctx }) => {
      const { username, password } = input;

      const user = await db.user.findUnique({
        where: { username },
      });

      if (!user || !(await verifyPassword(password, user.password))) {
        throw new Error("Invalid username or password");
      }
      const session = encrypt(username);

      console.log("session", session);

      ctx.resHeaders.set("Set-Cookie", session);

      return { success: true, username: user.username };
    }),
});


my trpc api route
import { fetchRequestHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/fetch";
import { type NextResponse, type NextRequest } from "next/server";

import { env } from "@/env";
import { appRouter } from "@/server/api/root";
import { createTRPCContext } from "@/server/api/trpc";

/**
 * This wraps the `createTRPCContext` helper and provides the required context for the tRPC API when
 * handling a HTTP request (e.g. when you make requests from Client Components).
 */
const createContext = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
  return createTRPCContext({
    headers: req.headers,
    resHeaders: res.headers,
  });
};

const handler = (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) =>
  fetchRequestHandler({
    endpoint: "/api/trpc",
    req,
    router: appRouter,
    createContext: () => createContext(req, res),
    onError:
      env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? ({ path, error }) => {
            console.error(
              `❌ tRPC failed on ${path ?? "<no-path>"}: ${error.message}`
            );
          }
        : undefined,
  });

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


my createTRPCContext
xport const createTRPCContext = async (opts: {
  headers: Headers;
  resHeaders: Headers;
}) => {
  const session = cookies().get("session");

  if (!session) {
    return {
      db,
      ...opts,
      session: null,
    };
  }

  interface MyJwtPayload extends JwtPayload {
    username: string;
  }
  const decoded = jwt.verify(
    session?.value,
    process.env.JWT_SECRET!
  ) as MyJwtPayload;

  const user = await db.user.findUnique({
    where: { username: decoded.username },
  });

  return {
    db,
    ...opts,
    session: { user },
  };
};


I get the error on this line in user router
 ctx.resHeaders.set("Set-Cookie", session);

also this is how i call the login from client

  const loginUser = api.user.login.useMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("data", data);
      router.push("/dashboard");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    },
  });

  const handleFormSubmit = (values: loginInputFormTypes) => {
    console.log(values);
    try {
      loginUser.mutate(values);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    }

    form.reset();
  };

